# Reviewing an append function for a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, append

This is a practice problem that I'm sure is correct, but after reviewing similar examples on the site, I feel the need to double check.

Consider this declaration of the nodes in a linked list of integers:

```
class LinkedListNode {
     int x;
     LinkedListNode next;
}
```

Make a *recursive method* append that satisfies this claim: If H is the head of the linked list of integers and t is an integer, then add(H, T) is linked list of integers which comes from adding T to the end the list with H as its head.

```
private Node append(Node H, int t){
    if (H == null) {
        H = new Node(x);
    }
    else {
        H.next = append(H.next, t);
    }
    return H;
}
```

I have reviewed other questions here, but I still have some doubts that I'm right. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you run your code and find out if it works? Also, I'd recommend changing your coding convention to use lowerCamelCase notation for variables and reserve capitalization for class names. Reason being is that at first glance, most people will read H as a class name instead of a variable. Changing this from `H` to `h` will clear this up a bit.

Comment: I think `H = new Node(x);` should be `H = new Node(t);`.

Comment: And `Node` should be `LinkdListNode`.  And `LinkedListNode` will need the constructor `LinkedListNode(int x)` declared.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a public method called append for the class LinkedListlooking like that:

```
public Node append(int t) {
    processAppend(firstNode, t);
}
```

and a private method processAppend, looking like that:

```
private Node processAppend(Node n, int t) {
    if (n == null) {
        Node nn = new Node(t);
        n.setNext(n);
    }
    else {
        return append(n.getNext(), t);
    }
}
```